# Disk performance utillity tool

Tags: windows-7, hard-disk, disk-analysis

I have an issue with my system which seems to be related with my disk (HDD). 
I want to confirm that disk is not working as it should. Is there any utility for this which runs on Windows 7?

Any alternative suggestion for disk performance monitoring is welcomed.

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: What should it analyze? Are you just looking for a "benchmark" – or rather for something checking for possible defects? What are the exact requirements, what statistics should be accounted for? For good suggestions, we'll need some more details. Suggested reading: [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [HD Tune Pro](http://www.hdtune.com/)

- has a trial version so it is gratis as a one-time use software
- Windows 7
- simple to use
- I've been using it for years, always happy with it

Error scan (quick and slow scan):

[image]

Health:

[image]

Speed map:

[image]

Performances:

[image]